# React Native TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple(color: '', boolean) not working on Android v6.0.1

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

**TouchableNativeFeedback hasn't always being defective for me. This particular snippet of code :**

```
    render() {
    const btnStyle = this.props.btnStyle;

    return(
      <TouchableNativeFeedback background={TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple('#60b0f4', false)} onPress={this.props.action}>
          <View style={btnStyle} /*onPress={this.props.action}*/>
            {
              this.state.fontLoaded ?
                <Text style={[this.props.textStyle, {fontFamily: 'montserrat-regular'}]}>{this.props.text}</Text>
                :
                <Text style={[this.props.textStyle, {fontFamily: 'sans-serif'}]}>{this.props.text}</Text>
            }
          </View>
      </TouchableNativeFeedback>
    );
  }
}
```

**has always worked until today. The button component doesn't respond as it should. There's no ripple effect as should happen, given 'background={TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple('#60b0f4', false)}'. Any help?**

Comment: Same issue. Did you find any solution?